# Is there a way to emphasize dynamic text on a website for SEO?

Tags: seo

I have a bit of dynamic text on my site, usually just 3 words, that changes quarterly. Specifically, this text is on my index page wrapped in an h1 tag. This same exact line of text can also be found on various other pages as well, wrapped in other paragraph tags, and maybe other 'p' tags in bold.

My question is: Can I somehow have this text 'stand out?' Is there possibly another section tag that I can wrap specific text in? With the goal being, a web crawler detects that some line of text is wrapped in a particular tag, that specific piece of text then becomes part of the meta description within the search results.

Comment: HTML mark-up has absolutely ***nothing*** to do with how Google or Bing selects SERP snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With the goal being, a web crawler detects that some line of text is wrapped in a particular tag, that specific piece of text then becomes part of the meta description within the search results.

Just have the dynamic text repeat in the meta description tag. Most search engines will look there when selecting the snippet to appear.  They may not use it 100% of the time, but given what you are attempting to do, that may be your best bet. The caveat is that if Google doesn't crawl you all that often, this won't work.